# How to set the preferred speed of car in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to create a traffic congestion dynamically by reducing the speed of the car.

```
for (Car car :cars) { 
  car = cars.get(uniform_discr(0,cars.size()-1));
  double currentSpeed = car.getSpeed(); // in meters per second

  // Define a random congestion factor (e.g., between 0.8 and 1.0)
  double minCongestionFactor = 0.8;
  double maxCongestionFactor = 1.0;
  double randomCongestionFactor = minCongestionFactor + Math.random() * (maxCongestionFactor - minCongestionFactor);

  // Calculate the adjusted speed
  double adjustedSpeed = currentSpeed * randomCongestionFactor;

  // Set the preferred speed for the car
  car.setPreferredSpeed(adjustedSpeed);
}
```

But I am getting the error,

> Description: The method setPreferredSpeed(double) is undefined for the type Car. Location: updated_Model_Trafic_flow_on_dynamic_ pricing2/Main/event1 - Event

Comment: What does the `setPreferredSpeed` method in `Car` look like, and are you sure it exists at that instance and is accessible?

Comment: Was there any other way, you could have given a more vague comment????  @chrisbyte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `Car` agent type is actually defined to be a car:
[image]

Only then does code-complete actually let you write this method:
[image]

PS: Always use code-complete, never type code yourself. This way, you always know upfront if a method is actually available or not